# Opening a pop up photo correctly on first click or hover

Tags: qgis-plugins

My website being developed with others is here:

https://www.victoriasforestryheritage.org.au/

I have used the qgis2web plug in to put three other maps on the site,
https://www.victoriasforestryheritage.org.au/showcase/maps.html

but this one at:

https://www.victoriasforestryheritage.org.au/maps/forestlocations/locationtest3/index.html#7/-36.719/146.133

is the first with photo popups, and it is in very draft form. All photos are 600px by 400px or vice versa.

If you open this map and hover on the photo point at, for example, Stringers Knob in the far East, you will see that one hover opens the photo but the photo "frame" does not open fully. A second hover will do that and the photo displays properly until the page is closed.

Using Inspect I find that this code:

```
<div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 103px;"><table>                    <tbody><tr>                        <th scope="row"></th>                        <td>Stringer's Knob</td>                    </tr>                    <tr>                        <td colspan="2"><img src="./LocationPhotos/vfh0137ed.JPG" <="" td="">                    </td></tr>                </tbody></table></div>
```

sets a style width of 103px. I know if in Inspect I remove this style and insert auto for the width in the relevant css the popup works correctly for me - I think.

What I cannot do, because of my limited coding understanding, is find these style statements and remove them etc to get the output I want - a final display on first hover.

Comment: Review this post: [Leaflet: adjust popup to picture size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38170366/5569709)